# For the following function, find an appropiate delta such that $|f(x,y) - 8 | < 0.1$

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus, inequality

Let $f(x,y) = 4y$. We know that $\lim_{(x,y) \to (1,2)} f(x,y) = 8$

Find a $\delta > 0 / ||(x,y) - (1,2)||_2 < \delta \Rightarrow |f(x,y) - 8| < 0.1$

I'm trying to find a $ \delta$ in terms of $\epsilon$ like usually and then replace epsilon by 0.1, but I get stuck everytime whenever I try to bring an inequality in

Any tips/useful inequalities would be greatly appreciated

(Also, if you have a table with simple and useful inequalities I'd also be thankful if you shared it. Nothing too complicated, this is an introduction to myltivariable calculus)

Answer (score 0):

You want $|f(x,y) - 8| <.1 \Leftarrow$

$|4y - 8| < .1 \Leftarrow$

$|y - 2| < .025 \Leftarrow$

$||(x,y) - (1,2)|| < .025$.

Trick is to realize the $x$ has no bearing.  And $||(x,y) - (1,2)|| < \delta \implies |y-2| < \delta$.

And as the function is simply multiplying by a constant we just need delta to be inversely proportional to the constant.

...

Formally:

If $||(x,y) - (1,2)|| < .025$ then

$\sqrt {(1-x)^2 + (2-y)^2} < 0.025$ and

$\sqrt{(2-y)^2 } \le \sqrt {(1-x)^2 + (2-y)^2} < 0.025$

$|y-2| < 0.025$

$|4y - 8| < 0.1$

$|f(x,y) - 8| < 0.1$.

=====

2nd go as the above was too slick.

$||(x,y) - (1,2)|| < \delta$

$\sqrt{(y-2)^2 + (1-x)^2} < \delta$

$(y-2)^2 + (1-x)^2 < \delta^2$

$(y-2)^2 < \delta^2 - (1-x)^2 < \delta^2$

$(y-2)^2 < \delta^2$

$|y-2| < \delta$

$|4y - 8| < 4\delta$

$|f(x,y) - 8| < 4\delta$.

We want $4\delta \le .1$.

So $\delta \le .025$ does it.

Comment: I'm having trouble between lines 3 and 4. How do you skip from the modulus to that norm?

Comment: Because if $||(x,y) - (1,2)|| < \delta$ then $|y - 2| < \delta$.  Notice those are backwards implication arrows.

Comment: If $(x,y)$ is within $\delta$ of $(1,2)$ then the absolute furthest $y$ can be for $2$ is $\delta$.  So $|y - 2| < \delta$.  If you like $||(x,y)-(1,2)|| = \sqrt{(y-2)^2 + (1-x)^2} < \delta$ so $(y-2)^2 + (1-x)^2 < \delta^2$ so $(y-2)^2 < \delta^2 - (1-x)^2 < \delta^2$ so $|y-2| < \delta$).